# Haproxy doesnt work for 8081 but works for 8080

Tags: haproxy

I am new to HAproxy,  I have installed and setup config. Everything works fine for 8080 but when i change the port to 8081 it doesnt work.

8081  always gives 503 error which i believe  is the frontend is not finding backend.

```
frontend LB
bind *:8081   
mode http
acl site_dead nbsrv(Web_Servers) lt 2
monitor-uri /test
monitor fail  if site_dead
default_backend Web_Servers

backend Web_Servers
mode http
balance roundrobin
option forwardfor
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
server test-81 x.x.x.x:8081 check
```

When i give 8080 i get  service ready. But when i have 8081 i get 503. Appreciate help if someone can advise why it doesnt work for 8081

Answer (score 0):

You have your frontend binding to port 8081 and your backend server port set to 8081. Is the test-81 server truly listening on that port? Also, are you browsing the site on port 8081? If not, fix those things.

Comment: Yes aboslutely. I can connect with direct  server IP on 8081  on it only when i have HAproxy IP i have this issue.

Comment: Can you share the line in the HAProxy access log that corresponds to the failed request? Also, is HAProxy installed onto a different server than the web server? They aren’t trying to use the same port?

Comment: HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>   HAProxy is on a different server , it works fine with 8080 so if there was aconflict it should give me error  for 8080 . It happens only for 8081

Comment: @Robin we need to see the line from the HAProxy error log that corresponds to the failed request.  You might also try `curl -v  http://x.x.x.x:8081` from the HAProxy machine, where x.x.x.x is the backend.  The only probable explanation is a problem with the backend system or with reaching it, not HAProxy, and the curl command should also fail if that is true.

Comment: Curl works.. the  error log has error no backend servers available... NOTE: If i comment "#monitor fail  if site_dead"  it works fine.. can anyone explain why?

Comment: Alternatively , moving the health to backend worked

Comment: Monitor-uri is for external components to check. HAProxy will expose a health check URL. It’s not needed for normal backend server health checking. With what you have your ACL is true unless you have at least two servers up. You show one server in your example. You only need the check parameter on the server line. Do you have a log file /var/log/haproxy.log?